# SQL - How do I list rows from one table on the basis of them not appearing in another?

Tags: mysql, sql, datatables

I have a customers table (which contains customer ID and family name) and an orders table, and have to list the ID and names of customers that didn't place an order i.e do not appear in the orders table. I tried this:

```
SELECT custID,familyname
FROM customers
WHERE custID = 
(SELECT custID
FROM orders
WHERE COUNT(custID)<1);
```

but am getting an error. Do I have to use NOT EXIST? Or NOT IN?

Comment: There`s also a `LEFT JOIN b on..WHERE b.col IS NULL`

Answer (score 1):

You don't *have* to use `not exists`.  You should want to:

```
SELECT c.custID, c.familyname
FROM customers
WHERE not exists (select 1 from orders o where o.custId = c.custId);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use an outer join and filter in on those instances where there is no match:

```
select c.custid, c.familyname
  from customers c
  left join orders o
    on c.custid = o.custid
 where o.custid is null
```